# Type inference with pattern binder at sing @ in match case doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

Suppose `Lofty` is a sealed trait and `Earthy` is one of its case classes. In a match such as this:

```
loftyItem match {
...
 case e @ Earthy(x,y,z) => { foo(e) }
...
}
```

where `foo` expects an `Earthy` as argument, the compiler melts down because `e` is inferred only to be of type `Lofty`. I can work around this, but it doesn't fit my model of how things ought to be. (I'm working with Scala 2.13.5.) Can someone explain why the compiler's behavior makes sense, and make me happy with Scala again?

In response to comments, let me be more precise:

```
object QTest {
  trait Ethereal

  case class Lofty[A <: Ethereal](val slotMaybe: Option[A]) {
  }

  class Earthy(val field: Int) extends Ethereal

  object Earthy {
    def apply(fx: Int): Earthy = {
      new Earthy(fx)
    }

    def unapply(x: Ethereal): Option[Int] = x match {
      case y: Earthy => Some(y.field)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  def testReally(just: Lofty[Ethereal]):
      Lofty[Earthy] = {
    just.slotMaybe match {
      case Some(c) => c match {
        case cnfC @ Earthy(i) => {
          just.copy(slotMaybe = Some(cnfC))
        }
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException("oops")
      }
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException("oops")
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling this produces the error:

```
QTest.scala:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : QTest.Ethereal
 required: QTest.Earthy
          just.copy(slotMaybe = Some(cnfC))
```

I obviously jumped to a conclusion, but the full example seems to have the same issue. Why does the compiler infer type `Ethereal` for `cnfC` instead of `Earthy`? Even if the compiler gets the type right for most uses of `@`, why does it get it wrong here?

Comment: Is your workaround `case e: Earthy => { foo(e) }` ?

Comment: @gael J Yes, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SLS 8.1.3 Pattern Binders](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders) states

> A pattern `p` implies a type `T` if the pattern matches only values of the type `T`.

The pattern `Earthy(i)` in

```
case cnfC @ Earthy(i) =>
```

represents [extractor pattern](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns) meaning it will match according to your definition of `unapply` which is

```
object Earthy {
  def unapply(x: Ethereal): Option[Int] = ???
}
```

Because the declared type of `x` is wider `Ethereal` instead of narrower `Earthy` it will not match

> ... only values of the type `T`

where `T = Earthy`, but instead it can match other subtypes of `Ethereal` as well. Hence the compiler can only be sure it will be *some* `Ethereal`.

If you wish to make it compile with the extractor pattern then either declare your `unapply` as

```
object Earthy {
  def unapply(x: Earthy): Option[Int] = ???
}
```

or better yet use case class instead which gets a correct `unapply` automagically

```
case class Earthy(field: Int) extends Ethereal
```

Comment: Yes, when I make it a case class the problem goes away. But for extraneous reasons I don't want to make it a case class. What magic does `case class` use to narrow the type? Is there a way of displaying the unapply method produced by `case class`?

Comment: @airfoyle For example in REPL you can see with `:settings -Xprint:typer`. It should be something like something like `def unapply(x: Earthy): Option[Int] = Option(x).map(_.field) `.